# Why is Bulma Calendar on ReactJS not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bulma

I am trying to use bulma calendar on my current react project. I followed the documentation but it doesn't work. Here is how i import and initialized in `componentDidMount`

```
import bulmaCalendar from 'bulma-calendar/dist/js/bulma-calendar.min.js';
import 'bulma-calendar/dist/css/bulma-calendar.min.css'
```

in componentDidMount i just copy paste the example from site's [documentation](https://creativebulma.net/product/calendar/demo)

```
componentDidMount() {
  var calendars = bulmaCalendar.attach('[type="date"]');
  calendars.forEach(calendar => {
    // Add listener to date:selected event
    calendar.on("date:selected", date => {
      console.log(date);
    });
  });

  // To access to bulmaCalendar instance of an element
  const element = document.querySelector("#startdate");
  if (element) {
    // bulmaCalendar instance is available as element.bulmaCalendar
    element.bulmaCalendar.on("select", datepicker => {
      console.log(datepicker.data.value());
    });
  }
}
```

But this is not working, it says

> "error:  TypeError: document.createRange(...)._cxualFragment is not a
>   function"

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This bulma calendar plugin is outside react-DOM, that is, it can't be recognized as a react component. Follow react's documentation on using external DOM,  https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your import like

```
import 'bulma-calendar/dist/js/bulma-calendar.min.js';
import 'bulma-calendar/dist/css/bulma-calendar.min.css';
```

and move these imports to root index.js of project for accessibility of bulmaCalendar function in your app